# Is sharing a link via Google+ in the cards?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, site-promotion

We can tweet links for site promotion, facebook them, our email seeking outside experts. Will posting to Google+ be in our toolkits any time soon?

Comment: Aaaand, there they are. Enjoy :)

Comment: I a true LOL occurred. To think I've driven by StackExchange so many times in solving my programming issues, to only register yesterday as I discovered RPG.StackExchange.com and today on ServerFault. Methinks this is my kind of people!

Comment: As Google+ has ceased to be, I think it's safe to say this is no longer planned, so I've removed the [status-planned] tag :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was just added to SO I'd imagine that support for SE sites is right around the corner (maybe the next build?)

From [Geoff Dalgas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120389/170797)

> We have implemented Google+ share links on Stack Overflow and will be rolling these out to the rest of the network very soon.

Comment: In the interim you can, of course, share the links manually.

Comment: Manual will be used. Thanks for the rapid response!